# Audio hardware latency changes when I connect headset. [Android]

Tags: android, audio, opensl

Audio hardware latency (from speakers to mic) changes when I connect headset. What might be the reason of that variance? how to make the hardware latency constant regardless of whether headphones connected or not?

Any comments and answers are appreciated!

Comment: On at least phone I worked with there was an amplifier for the loudspeaker that required a 50 ms wait when being powered up to avoid clicks/pops. This wait was not needed for headphones.

Comment: @Michael hmm..that's interesting. What kind of device did you use?

Comment: I think this was either the Sony XPeria Z or ZL. The wait was in the ALSA drivers, so it wasn't something app devs had to think about. But the latency would differ depending on whether the output was routed to the loudspeaker or headphones.